# BASH - Variable name from variable

Tags: bash

my code

```
TOTAL=${#FOO_5[*]} // COUNT ITEMS IN ARRAY
```

what if code

```
ARRAY_NAME="FOO_5"
TOTAL=${#${!ARRAY_NAME}[*]} //error
```

please fix

Comment: Don't guess randomly at shell syntax.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to indirect parameter expansion, the array index is considered part of the parameter name. Unfortunately, you cannot chain parameter expansions; you'll also need a intermediate variable.

```
ARRAY_NAME="FOO_5[*]"
FULL=${!ARRAY_NAME}
TOTAL=${#FULL}
```

Comment: ugh. recommend associative arrays before this hack. Especially to "all-caps variable users".

Comment: Also forgot to mention, remember `"${#a[*]}"` and `"${#a[@]}"` are equivalent, so this is probably not what he wants. `full=("${!arr}") total=${#full[@]}`. I'd just `eval`.

Comment: Right, I missed the comment that said "count items in array".