# Bash scripting: find variable with lowest value

Tags: bash, variables, min

I have script containin 4 variables. Need a function that will take values of those 4 variables and return name of the one that has lowest value.
So let's say that i have:
`var1=55`
`var2=71`
`var3=30`
`var4=42`
then i would like it to return as an answer: `var3`
Can anyone help? I need easiest way to solve that but appreciate any working solution.

Comment: Is this home work? What code have you written so far? How do you gather the input? Please be more specific with questions. Post your code. Let readers know what you have tried. This is not a place for free answers.

Comment: little hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882089/bash-variable-name-from-variable

Comment: No it's not homework.
Code i have came up to till now is:
`#!/bin/bash

x=12
y=35
z=7
q=24
va=0
vb=0
na=0
nb=0
minval=0
minname=0

if (( $x < $y )) ; then va=$x na=x ; else va=$y na=y ; fi
if (( $z < $q )) ; then vb=$z nb=z ; else vb=$q nb=q ; fi
if (( $va < $vb )) ; then minval=$va minname=$na ; else minval=$vb minname=$nb ; fi
echo $minval
echo $minname
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I don't think your values are in an array and that you want to know which index in the array is smallest - I think your values are in individual variables and you want to know the name of the variable containing the smallest value.  If that is really what you are asking try this:

```
func()
{
  minvar=$1
  eval minval=\$$1
  for i in $*
  do
    eval var=\$$i
    # echo $i=$var
    if [[ $var -lt $minval ]]
    then
      minvar=$i
      minval=$var
      # echo min=$i
    fi
  done
}

var1=55
var2=71
var3=30
var4=42
func var1 var2 var3 var4
echo $minvar=$minval
```

Comment: Seem to work as i need, but I need to investigate it further, Im beginer and im not familiar with `\$$1` or `\$$i` don't know what it does actually. But yeah it finds smallest variable so I can move on.